# How can I render Emojis on Openlayers 4 map?

Tags: javascript, typescript, openlayers, geojson, emoji

I am told to render emojis on an openlayers 4 map.

Now I found several examples on how to use custom map markers, but that does not exactly fit my needs.

Is there a way to render emojis on an openlayers 4 map?

This is the test data I used (GeoJSON):

```
 {
    features: [
        {
            type: 'Feature',
            id: '1016392629',
            geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [6.0, 6.0]
            },
            properties: {
                text: '\u1F31E',
            }
        },
        {
            type: 'Feature',
            id: '-2026663018',
            geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [0.0, 0.0]
            },
            properties: {
                text: '\u1F31E',
            }
        }
    ],
    type: 'FeatureCollection'
 }
```

and using a style function:

```
    style: (feature: Feature) => {
        const { font, textBaseline, fillColor } = this.options;
        const s: ol.style.Style = new ol.style.Style({
            text: new ol.style.Text({
                text: feature.getProperties().text,
                font,
                textBaseline,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: fillColor
                })
            }),
            zIndex: 1
        });

        return s;
    }
```

But this only gives me:

[image]

Comment: If the answer resolved your issue, please consider to **accept the answer** by clicking the `v` sign next to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emoji in JS has two characters. (UTF-16 need to be represented with two codes)

So smiley emoji is: `'\uD83D\uDE00'` =

Now, your emoji, `'\u1F31E'` (Sunny), will be: `'\uD83C\uDF1E'` = .

Read on about lead-surrogate and tail-surrogate at: [medium.com: emojis-in-javascript](https://medium.com/reactnative/emojis-in-javascript-f693d0eb79fb)

Simple google finds me online resources mapping the emoji at: [timwhitlock.info emoji tables](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode)
And you can inspect each character [timwhitlock.info inspect 1F31E](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect/hex/1F31E)